# Why does returning a cached jQuery promise inside a then block fails to resolve it?

Tags: jquery

I leverage jQuery promises to cache AJAX requests, the approach seems to break when I attempt to return a cached promise inside a then clause; I am unsure why this is happening and would like to know if there is a way to resolve it.

If I fake the key and place the `if (self.fGetSearchResults.oCache[...` block right under the cache definition outside of the `then` block the code works as expected.

```
MCG.searchControls.fGetSearchResults = function fGetSearchResults() {
    var self = this;

    var oDeferred = $$.Deferred(); // `new` keyword is optional and we don't like it
    var oPromise = oDeferred.promise();

    self.fGetSearchResults.oCache = self.fGetSearchResults.oCache || {}; // creates a persistent cache across function calls

    // perform the search
    $$.when(
        self.fPromiseOfFilterObject() 
    ).done(
        function fDoneCallback(oFilterObject) {
            /* create the RecordListService parameters which we will query with */
            ..
            var oRecordListServiceParametersAsKey = JSON.stringify(oRecordListServiceParameters);
            // leverage our cache here
            if (self.fGetSearchResults.oCache[oRecordListServiceParametersAsKey] !== undefined) {
                return self.fGetSearchResults.oCache[oRecordListServiceParametersAsKey];
            } else {
                self.fGetSearchResults.oCache[oRecordListServiceParametersAsKey] = oPromise; // cache the result for next time
            }

            // do the ajax call now
            $.orchestracmsRestProxy.doAjaxServiceRequest('ocms_socfp.RecordListService', oRecordListServiceParameters,
                function(status, json) {
                    ...
                    oDeferred.resolve(json)
                });
        });
    return oPromise; // return a our promise object which will resolve at some point
}
```

Comment: Right off the bat, I'd say your .done syntax may be wrong.  .done(function(oFilterObject) would be the expected.

Comment: @Chris Caviness: what's wrong with it?

Comment: I don't know that anything is, just that jQuery's .done is expecting a function or an array of functions.  Using a function declaration isn't something I've tried before.  function foo(bar) is a declaration {}, function(bar) {} is an anonymous function.  I would expect to see .done(funcname) or .done(function(parm){}) not .done(function foo(bar){});  I guess function foo(bar) is going to return itself so probably not an issue, just an unexpected syntax.

Comment: I'm assuming you build oRecordListServiceParameters from oFilterObject.  self.fPromiseOfFilterObject() returns a promise defined how?  I'm asking because I think you may be able to eliminate the caching completely by adding a parm to oFilterObject.  Something like oFilterObject.servicePromise = {} then your code becomes return oFIlterObject.servicePromise || oDeferred.promise(oFilterObject.servicePromise)

Comment: @Chris Caviness: it has nothing to do with jquery. In JS you **can** use a function declaration in the context of a function expression. Then it will not be declared, but the name will be available in the context of the function itself.

Comment: @ChrisCaviness yes the reason I do so is for debugging purposes - tracing the stack call is easier when you got named functions.